# how to make my android app directs to my fanpage with a `like` button and not as a regular page?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a fanpage and an android app that directs to my fanpage.

It uses this url: `fb://profile/86232932633`

I'm not familiar with this format. someone knows what is it?

not a web-url for sure.

how can I change it to show the target page as fanpage and not a regular profile?

`fb://page/86232932633`?

i.e. shows `like` button` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed :

fb://profile/86232932633

to

fb://page/86232932633